# Getting "Vendor autoload is not found." error even the composer install succeeded

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

When i open Magento in browser i got

> Autoload error
>
> Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.

even i have run

```
composer update
composer install
```

on the root folder and it says

> Nothing to install, update or remove

Is there somewhere I can dig to figure out why the autoload is still failing?

Comment: vendor directory is exist in your magento root?

Comment: yes, and there is autoload.php in the vendor folder with a lot of other sub-folders.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to run the following commands and then check.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: The problem was resolved by set the ownership of all files under Magento folder
```chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/magento```

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the below  step  but still getting error   **"Vendor autoload is not found." please Run Composer under root directory.**
please help how can resolve

/var/www/html/magento2/ composer update

/var/www/html/magento2/  composer install

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/